# How to access all members of a public distribution list?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a public distribution list called "DistList XX Group".
The email address of that list is "DL-XX_Group@abc.com".

Is it possible to access it using something like this?

```
Dim rm As DistListItem
Set rm = DistListItem("DL-XX_Group@abc.com")
Set rm = DistListItem("DistList XX Group")
```

Comment: do [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-list-all-the-members-of-a-microsoft-outlook-distribution-list/) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Use VBA to Create a List of Exchange GAL Members](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/use-vba-to-create-a-list-of-exchange-gal-members/)

**List Members of a Distribution list**
This macro lists the email address and phone numbers of the members of a specific Exchange distribution group.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetDGMembers()

Dim olAL As AddressList
Dim olEntry As AddressEntry
Dim olMember As AddressEntry

Dim strName As String
Dim strAddress As String
Dim strPhone As String

Dim i As Long
Dim lMemberCount As Long

Dim objMail As MailItem

Set olAL = Session.AddressLists("Global Address List")

Set objMail = CreateItem(olMailItem)

' enter the list name
Set olEntry = olAL.AddressEntries("DistList XX Group")

' get count of dist list members
lMemberCount = olEntry.Members.Count

' loop through dist list and extract members
For i = 1 To lMemberCount
    Set olMember = olEntry.Members.Item(i)
    strName = olMember.Name
    strAddress = olMember.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    strPhone = olMember.GetExchangeUser.BusinessTelephoneNumber
    
    objMail.Body = objMail.Body & strName & " -- " & strAddress & " -- " & strPhone & vbCrLf
Next

objMail.Display

End Sub
```

No GAL available for testing.

Comment: The OP actually asked about `DistListItem` object, bot a GAL object.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you know the folder where the DL resides. Assuming it is the default Contacts folder:

```
set folder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
set DL = folder.Items("DL-XX_Group@abc.com")
if not (DL is Nothing) Then
  MsgBox DL.DLName
End If
```

If the DL does not exist, folder.Items() will raise an exception (that you can handle).